# File Not Found. in ClientContext.Site.OpenWeb

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I just tring to open the subsite using the CSOM. I'm geting the below error in clientContext.ExecuteQuery().
site URL is https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/Customer Orders

> File Not Found.

```
        cTokenHelper.TrustAllCertificates();
            clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(SPHostUrl, accessToken);
        Uri oUri = new Uri(SiteUrl);
        oWebsite = clientContext.Site.OpenWeb(oUri.AbsolutePath);
        clientContext.Load(oWebsite);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.openweb(v=office.15).aspx)

> Parameters
>   *strUrlType*: System.String
>
> Specifies the **server-relative** URL or **web-relative** URL of the site to open. If strurl is empty, the top-level site must be opened.

So what you need to pass as a parameter to OpenWeb is the **relative** URL. Instead of ["https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/Customer Orders"](https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/Customer%20Orders) it is just "Customer Orders"